# Restrict my user to Recall the server if my file Transfer service is running

Tags: android, web-services, service

We are developing a `school application` in Which, we are trying to fetch data from server. It is working fine. After fetching data, we are trying to download a file using create a service **my file transfer running** in background. During this, we want to restrict my user to recall the server if my file Transfer service is running.

We are using the below code which is display all the service but can not find my service in the list of services but in background my file Transfer is Running Even we show in **setting -> Running application** that also show service is running

My Class Looks Like ... Can anyone suggest me some alternate way??

```
    public class Getdata {

    Intent DownloadServiceIntent;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    Alert_Dialog_Manager alert = new Alert_Dialog_Manager();

    // Database_Handler Object
    Database_Handler dbh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Getdata(Context context,List<NameValuePair> request) {


        mContext = context;
        Request = request;
        DataUrl = mConnection.fun_GetWebserviceURL()+"Gatway.php";

        // get Database
        dbh = new Database_Handler(mContext);
        db = dbh.get_writeabledb();

        boolean checkservice = isServiceRunning(mContext);
        Log.d("boolean Value",""+checkservice); // Return Always false But My Service Is Running In Background
        if(checkservice){

            alert.showAlertDialog(mContext, " Request Alert ","File Download Started In Background \nPlease Try After Sometime!!", false);

        }else{
            // Get Data
            new GetDataService().execute();
        }
    }

    class GetDataService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait For Few Minutes...");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Database... ");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //Getting Data From Server

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            // Starting service for Download Files..
            DownloadServiceIntent = new Intent(mContext,FileTransferService.class);
            mContext.startService(DownloadServiceIntent);

        } // GetWebService


    public boolean isServiceRunning(Context mContext){

         boolean isServiceFound = false;

         final ActivityManager activityManager =(ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);        
         List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

         for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++)
         {
         Log.d("Service ClassName ","Service" + i + ":" + services.get(i).service.getClassName().toString());
         if (services.get(i).service.getClassName().toString().equals("com.soch.webservice.FileTransferService"))
         {
                     isServiceFound = true;
         }

         }
         return isServiceFound;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Alternative way can be  this:

```
if(startService(someIntent) != null) { 
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no service running, starting service..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Edit**

I would recommend to use an static boolean variable which will check the status of Running services.

[Also check this link, it'll help for sure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html#foreground)

Comment: someIntent means MyService Intent??

Comment: Yes. Your Service Intent

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this.

private boolean isMyServiceRunning()
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if (BgTimerService.class.getName().equals(
                service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I Could Not Find My Service In The List But Service Is running In Background